# list box notifications

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi

I have dialog box with two controls: **tree view** and **list box**. 
I also have message handler for my dialog box.

```
 case WM_NOTIFY:
        {  
          switch(LOWORD(wParam)) 
            {
                case IDC_LIST1: //we NEVER comes here
                      if(((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code == NM_CLICK)
                      {
                          //do some work; 
                          return (INT_PTR)TRUE; 
                      }
                      break; 
                case IDC_TREE1: 
                      if(((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code == NM_DBLCLK)
                      {
                         //do some work;
                         return (INT_PTR)TRUE;  
                      }
                      break;
            }
        }
        break;
```

So, I can't understand why notifications from tree box comes succesfully, but notifications from list box never comes, despite the fact that in the properties of  list box' control **Notify** value is set **TRUE**. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's check the documentation.

[List Box Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775149%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> LBS_NOTIFY
>
> Causes the list box to send a notification code to the parent window whenever the user clicks a list box item (**[LBN_SELCHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775161(v=vs.85).aspx)**), double-clicks an item (**[LBN_DBLCLK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775153(v=vs.85).aspx)**), or cancels the selection (**[LBN_SELCANCEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775159(v=vs.85).aspx)**).

[LBN_SELCHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775161%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Notifies the application that the selection in a list box has changed as a result of user input. **The parent window of the list box receives this notification code through the WM_COMMAND message.**

[LBN_DBLCLK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Notifies the application that the user has double-clicked an item in a list box. **The parent window of the list box receives this notification code through the WM_COMMAND message.**

[LBN_SELCANCEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775159%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Notifies the application that the user has canceled the selection in a list box. **The parent window of the list box receives this notification code through the WM_COMMAND message.**

Conclusion: List boxes use `WM_COMMAND` to notify the parent, not `WM_NOTIFY`.